# submit() is not triggering at all

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-submit

I am unsure why `submit()` is not triggering at all. The click event and underlying AJAX call is working fine, but the form is not submitting. I have also tried `$("#storeForm").unbind().submit();` and it has no effect.

```js
$(document).on("click", '#submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var frm = $("#storeForm");
  var address = $("#address").val();
  var state = $("#state option:selected").text();
  var city = $("#city").val();
  var country = "USA";
  var addressToSearch = state + " " + state + " " + country;
  var urlGeoCode = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIzaSyAfAyG4l207wcJUn-D8XsOUZvCSwJv27zs&&address=' + addressToSearch;

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: urlGeoCode,
    success: function(result) {
      var location = result.results[0].geometry.location;
      $("#longitude").val(location.lng);
      $("#latitude").val(location.lat);
      $('#storeForm').submit();
    },
  });
});
```

**Edited:** the result  resultOutput to proper format

Comment: Show us the `storeForm`'s Html

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Does `#storeForm` exist and is there only one of them? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: don't use `id="submit"`. additionally, i'd start by binding to the form's submit event rather than click event, then in ajax success, submit the form rather than calling jquery's submit handler. `$('#storeForm')[0].submit();`

Comment: A click is not a form submission, and you are stopping event propogation which will likely stop the form submitting. Call it on the form and bind to the submit event eg  $("#storeForm").submit(function(){});

Comment: @KevinB: issue was what you stated, i am extremely pissed at my self now, thanks mate, you made my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's this *wonderful* browser feature that takes your `id="submit"` and turns it into a property on the form. This has the unfortunate side effect of overwriting the form node's `.submit` method, which is why jQuery is unable to submit said form.

Solution of course is to remove `id="submit"`, possibly replacing it with something else or handling the submit a different way.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue does not relate to the triggering of the `submit()` event at all. If you check the console you'll see an error:

> resultOutput is not defined

This is because you have a syntax error in the way you're accessing the response text in the `success` handler. As a result, `submit()` is not even being called.

To fix this you need to change `var location = resultOutput.geometry.location;` to `var location = result.results[0].geometry.location;`. This will then get the correct data before submitting your form. Try this:

```js
$(document).on("click", '#submit', function(e) {
  var urlGeoCode = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIzaSyAfAyG4l207wcJUn-D8XsOUZvCSwJv27zs&&address=Florida Florida Orlando';

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: urlGeoCode,
    success: function(result) {
      var location = result.results[0].geometry.location;
      $("#longitude").val(location.lng);
      $("#latitude").val(location.lat);
      $('#storeForm').submit();
    }
  });
});

$('#storeForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('form submission...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="storeForm">
  <input type="text" id="longitude" />
  <input type="text" id="latitude" />
</form>

<button type="button" id="submit">Get location...</button>
```

Comment: that was a typo, that i placed while templating my code for SOF. But its actually what @KevinB stated. Thanks for consideration.